# Dynamically changing windows saving directory?

Tags: java, c++, c, file

Is there a system property in windows that tells programs where their save location is?

My goal is to create a program which, on startup changes the default file path save location.

When the program shuts down, the default file location would go back to normal.

Comment: Err ... no, there isn't.  Furthermore, changing environment variables for other programs is a bad idea, even if you can implement it reliably.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea. The only issue I see is if my program crashes somehow and doesn't revert the old file path.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, as stated, this question is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Your real problem is that you want to control where your program's state is saved.

The real solution is to change your program so that it saves its state to a >>specified<< directory ... rather than relying on a "default save directory" (which is not a well defined concept on Windows or any other OS) and changing that to something else, temporarily.

Comment: You are right, and thanks for linking the XY problem. So this is more of somehow accessing each program's respective state save directory and modifying that?

Comment: Well, in Unix systems, there is very well a "well defined" path where to save program configuration, etc., called home-directory.

Comment: *"So this is more of somehow accessing each program's respective state save directory and modifying that?"* - The solution is to >>tell<< each program where to save its state.  That may involve setting a property or environment variable or changing a registry setting, or passing it a command line parameter ... or changing the program so that you can so one of the above.

Comment: @Olaf.  No there isn't.  That is a >>convention<<.  And actually, there are other conventions too ... depending on the nature of the program.

Comment: Not on Linux desktop systems at least and for environments which follow FreeDesktop standard, which includes Gnome and KDE for instance.

Comment: Erm ... if Tomcat ever saves stuff in its home directory, I'm going to start looking for my shotgun!

Comment: For system, there are /etc` and `/var`, of course! We were talking about desktop applications I presumed.

Comment: So yes.  What I said in my Answer is correct :-).  You are making assumptions that are not warranted.